# Found this on the lock screen does it mean its on his phone

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

[image]

I came across this on siris suggested apps

I am not familiar with iphones....
So my question is; if these apps come up under Siri's suggested apps. Does it mean that the suggested app is installed on the phone?

Comment: ...  you don't trust him, yet it's you snooping on **his** phone...

Comment: I hate to tell you, but yes - your 30-something boyfriend plays Candy Crush games.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is exactly what it means. Siri app suggestions are apps that the iPhone expects the user to open frequently.

None of those apps appear unusual to me. Perfectly normal and popular apps for any iPhone user.

Edit: Just so you know, SE keeps a copy of edits to questions.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark as solved.

Comment: How do I mark it as solved

Comment: There should be a check [tick] mark below the 'score' to the left of the answer. Click that. Only the person who asked the question can see it.